Help review my schematic for a LiPo + USB power supply and charger
I've recently redesigned this schematic based on the feedback I've received on an earlier post.
Questions:

Will power source switching MOSFETs work in the configuration I'm using?
Will the tri-state stat output LEDs work? (Hi-Z state doesn't need to be considered.)

Thanks


This looks well thought out, logical and neat although a bit dissected. A block diagram might be more coherent. It appears to be functional to me.
Q1, and Q2 may get warm briefly on a transition starting up U3 or have a hard time and thus it may be worth simulating to check for Pd dynamic load effects.
A block diagram with a list of all I/O specs would make it better for others to show all functional features and I/O specs with the battery installed.
Vstat output has a  Vol/Io = RdsOn = 1V/4mA= 250 Ohm max.
With a suitable choice of ultrabright LEDs, you can use 1~2 mA with voltage drop calculations for red 1.85 V and green 2.85 V as my estimates to recalculate and use 2~5% of rated current.  This is recommended to prevent metallurgic long-term issues from lower LED currents, FWIW.**
Tri-state has both LEDs at half brightness unless you change red to blue or white then both 3.? V LEDs can be "off" at 2.5 V each although not 0 current. (**)
(edited)

I appreciate you taking the time to help a newbie out. I am new to this stuff and it's nice to have a guiding hand. Thanks

Did you mean "Q1,Q2 may get warm briefly", rather than "Q2,Q3 may get warm briefly"? I can't see Q3 on the schematic.

TY@ChesterGillon
